# Extract a module from a large java project

Tags: java, maven, weka

Recently, I am using the weka(A open source data mining software) do some classification job. I found Random Forest Algorithm was fit my object perfectly and achieve a highly accuracy. So I want to extract the Random Forest module and ignore other uncorrelated module. It is tedious to find all the java class that reference by RandomForst.java. So I want to write a program to extract RandomForst.java and its correlated class automatically.
At first, I use the “import" information of a java class to find class dependency, but it can't work to find the dependency of the same package. 
I'm not sure whether Maven can help me to find the dependency.
Do you have any idea ？Thanks.

Comment: Why don't you use the whole library as is? This is a far superior approach as you do not have to worry about doing all this work again when there is a new version / bugfix available. Also be aware that this library is published under the GPL license. By modifying that product and incorporating that into your software, also your software becomes subject to this license.

Comment: Thank you! Actually, I want to put it on Android, It is too big to use the whole library.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For such purposes I use a combination of Maven Shade plugin and Proguard plugin. The first one merges libraries into a single Uber-jar. And the second one can be used to cut off all the classes which are not used in your project: [Using Proguard to Shrink the Jar](http://www.cs.trinity.edu/~kseitz/tutorials/scalaWebApplet/WebAppletsInScala/node5.html). Proguard is an obfuscator and it may cut almost anything - i.e. unused interfaces or methods, so one needs to be accurate with it.

Answer (score 1):

You could use the Maven Shade plugin to create an uber JAR, and ask it to minimise the JAR. That produces a JAR that contains only the classes you use.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I have tried to minimize the JAR. But it's not not work for me. The class that uncorrelated(e.g. J48.java) to RandomForst.java is still in JAR. Would you give me some further information to set the pom.xml.